# How do particles entangle and how does polarization work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, polarization

I am trying to learn about how particles get [entangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) and when I searched it up I did not understand how [polarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization) worked. I am still in elementary school so if please make the definition simple! I am a big fan of physics and wanting to learn more!

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) is quite thorough - can you ask a more *specific question* what you don't understand?

Comment: To show what entanglement is I give you at first an example, what it is not. Suppose there are two balls, one red and one green. You are able to make a decision which color you want to take? So you are not blind. One of them - say the red - you are taking and the green is taking your friend. Any check of the distribution of the colors gave the same result. You have the red ball and your friend the green. Photons (the quanta of the electromagnetic radiation) instead of color property have other properties like their direction of their electric field component.

Comment: This [electric field component is directed perpendicular to the direction of propagation of the photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) (strongly spoken, in vacuum). From a thermal source like an electric bulb the direction of the electric field component for all the emitted photons is equally distributed all over 360°. Scientists have found so called quantum dots where takes place the emission of two photons at time. For such pairs of photons the directions of their electric field components are also equally distributed in space, but these directions are entangled.

Comment: Say, the one photons electric field component is directed to 0° respectively 180°, than the second photons electric field component is directed to 90° respectively 270°. We are not free to choose these directions. We are not able to measure these directions exact. We are changing in any case this directions during our measurement. This is what we call entanglement of two particles. We use this entanglement to send encrypted informations and at the same time to find out, is someone in our communication line.

Comment: You see the differences between the two color balls and the two entangled photons? For photons there is no chance to choose the directions during emission nor there is a change to measure these directions exactly. For the balls you are free to take the blue or the red. But there is a coincidence in the photon pair existence. Whenever we use for both photons two filters (polarizer grids) with the same orientation, than, if one of this photons goes through one filter the second photon does not goes through the second filter.

Comment: So we know, that the have had produced a pair of entangled particles. As well as we have used two balls of different colors.